# VS2015 complains about printf not inlined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, printf

I'm compiling a C++ file with VS2015 and /Wall.
I'm using the `printf` function.

I get:

```
warning C4710: 'int printf(const char *const ,...)': function not inlined
```

I understand about inlining. I've seen help about `__forceinline` in MS environment. I just don't understand why VS2015 is not using it properly through `stdio.h` and still generate the warning.

My `stdio.h` file is here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
```

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Edit:

Ok sample code goes like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
};
```

As for whether I want to use C or C++, I'm currently using Windows for development, but the file will eventually be compiled as C on HPUX. If this is the reason for the warning, I'd like to know as well.

Comment: Post some code that produces that error. And make up your mind if you are asking about C or C++.

Comment: Using the `Wall` option in MSVC is impractical. Try and include a a header from the standard library. You will probably get thousands of warnings. You should be using `W4` instead.

Comment: `warning C4710` is one of the most common and most generic warning VS (`cl.exe`) spits out. (It is just saying "I didn't inline the `printf`" -- I don't care...) You can simply disable reporting by adding `/wd4710` to your compiler string. I use `/Wall`, then have a handful of the nonsensical warnings I don't care about disabled (`4710` being one) If it is critical to you that the function be inlined, then you need to worry about the warning for that function -- which is almost never the case if you just let the compiler do its job and choose.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was just wondering why MS didn't fix their own headers to use their own extensions.

Comment: It really depends on the warning level you are using. `/W1 - /Wall`. I like seeing every warning, but `/Wall` really means ALL. (~10 I don't care about). Thankfully you can display full warnings with `/Wall`, but disable the common, "not relevant" ones with `/wdXXXX` where `XXXX` is the warning code. It let's you tailor the warnings you want to see. You can literally get thousands of `4710` warnings on a large project where VS is just piping up "I didn't inline this one, or that one...."

Comment: As an example, in the little batch file I use to compile small C programs, I use `cl /nologo /Wall /wd4244 /wd4255 /wd4668 /wd4706 /wd4710 /wd4711 /wd4996 /Ox /Foobj/%~1 /Febin/%~1 /Tc %~2`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler tries to inline some functions (in this case `printf()` in order to achieve performance or disk space, as described [here in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4710?view=vs-2019). However, you can disable these warnings by:

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma warning (disable : 4710)
#endif
```

or in the CMake:

```
if (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "/wd4710") 
endif()
```

Edit:

In modern idiomatic CMake, it's best to avoid directly editing the CMAKE_C_FLAGS variable.

You can do the following instead.

```
add_compile_options(
  $<$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/wd4710>
)
```

Or you can even disable the warnings only for a single target with

```
target_compile_options(YourTargetName
  $<$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/wd4710>
)
```

Comment: ``/Wall`` turns on all warnings in Visual Studio. Some of them are just informative, and as such tend to be a lot of noise (like C4710 and C4820).  Some are more useful than others, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/compiler-warnings-that-are-off-by-default?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn true. I tried to make code snipets as consise as possible to avoid any confusion.